# How to find count of values within certain range in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, distribution

I have a pandas dataframe which contains a list of error values. I want to find the proportion of my errors in certain ranges e.g. what percentage of my error is within +-1%, +-5%, +-10%, +-20% and +-50% etc. A histogram of my data is shown below:

[image]

So far I have looked at functions such as pd.cut() and plt.hist() but no libraries seem to give me the answer where my ranges overlap each other so I'm having to resort to a very long custom made function - which is below:

```
def error_distribution(df):

  total_length = len(df.index)
  one_perc = five_perc = ten_perc = fifteen_perc = twenty_perc = thirty_perc \
    = fourty_perc = fifty_perc = over_fifty = 0

  for index, row in df.iterrows():
    value = abs(row['Errors'])

    if value <= 0.01:
      one_perc += 1
      five_perc += 1
      ten_perc += 1
      fifteen_perc += 1
      twenty_perc += 1
      thirty_perc += 1
      fourty_perc += 1
      fifty_perc += 1
    elif value <= 0.05:
      five_perc += 1
      ten_perc += 1
      fifteen_perc += 1
      twenty_perc += 1
      thirty_perc += 1
      fourty_perc += 1
      fifty_perc += 1      
    elif value <= 0.1:
      ten_perc += 1
      fifteen_perc += 1
      twenty_perc += 1
      thirty_perc += 1
      fourty_perc += 1
      fifty_perc += 1
    elif value <= 0.15:
      fifteen_perc += 1
      twenty_perc += 1
      thirty_perc += 1
      fourty_perc += 1
      fifty_perc += 1
    elif value <= 0.2:
      twenty_perc += 1
      thirty_perc += 1
      fourty_perc += 1
      fifty_perc += 1
    elif value <= 0.3:
      thirty_perc += 1
      fourty_perc += 1
      fifty_perc += 1
    elif value <= 0.4:
      fourty_perc += 1
      fifty_perc += 1
    elif value <= 0.5:
      fifty_perc += 1
    else:
      over_fifty += 1

  print("Sub  1%: {0:.2f}%".format(one_perc/total_length*100))
  print("Sub  5%: {0:.2f}%".format(five_perc/total_length*100))
  print("Sub 10%: {0:.2f}%".format(ten_perc/total_length*100))
  print("Sub 15%: {0:.2f}%".format(fifteen_perc/total_length*100))
  print("Sub 20%: {0:.2f}%".format(twenty_perc/total_length*100))
  print("Sub 30%: {0:.2f}%".format(thirty_perc/total_length*100))
  print("Sub 40%: {0:.2f}%".format(fourty_perc/total_length*100))
  print("Sub 50%: {0:.2f}%".format(fifty_perc/total_length*100))
  print("Over 50%: {0:.2f}%".format(over_fifty/total_length*100))
```

And the output I'm looking for is this:

```
error_distribution(error_dataset1)
```

Output:

```
Sub  1%: 16.55%
Sub  5%: 56.61%
Sub 10%: 71.62%
Sub 15%: 78.53%
Sub 20%: 82.97%
Sub 30%: 88.46%
Sub 40%: 91.09%
Sub 50%: 92.59%
Over 50%: 7.41%
```

Does anyone know of a standard library that could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=(200,))
count, division = np.histogram(arr, bins=[0, .01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1])
print(count, division)
```